# Flutter Web: SFTP returns "UnimplementedError: Native socket is not supported on web"

Tags: flutter, dart, sftp

I'm building a flutter web app (debugging using chrome) and in it I have to make SFTP calls to pull files from a host server. My code breaks at:

```
final socket = await SSHSocket.connect(<url>, <port>);
```

I've used many different packages to try to connect, the current one I am using is dartssh2. According to the documentation, dartssh2 has web support so I'm not sure why I am having an issue connection.

Documentation can be found at:

https://pub.dev/packages/dartssh2

The only way to provide a full code snippet for replication would involve me releasing sensitive variables such as my login info, but my snippet is setup like so:

```
//////globals.dart

76    Future<void> getStatsContent() async {
78      final socket = await SSHSocket.connect(<url>, <port>);
79    
81      final client = SSHClient(
82        socket,
83        username: <username>,
84        onPasswordRequest: () => <password>,
85      );
86    
89      final sftp = await client.sftp();
90      final file = await sftp.open('stats.json');
91    
94      final content = await file.readBytes();
95    
98      statsContent = json.decode(latin1.decode(content));
99    
102      client.close();
103      await client.done;
104    }
```

A full detail of my terminal:

```
dart_sdk.js:5397 Uncaught (in promise) Error: UnimplementedError: Native socket is not supported on web
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (dart_sdk.js:5397:11)
    at connectNativeSocket (ssh_socket_js.dart.lib.js:22:17)
    at connectNativeSocket.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (dart_sdk.js:40710:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (dart_sdk.js:40742:7)
    at Object.connectNativeSocket (ssh_socket_js.dart.lib.js:21:18)
    at connect (ssh_socket_js.dart.lib.js:29:36)
    at connect.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (dart_sdk.js:40710:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (dart_sdk.js:40742:7)
    at SSHSocket.connect (ssh_socket_js.dart.lib.js:28:20)
    at getStatsContent (globals.dart:78:34)
    at getStatsContent.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (dart_sdk.js:40710:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (dart_sdk.js:40742:7)
    at Object.getStatsContent (globals.dart:76:29)
    at guildselect.dart:250:51
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (dart_sdk.js:40710:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (dart_sdk.js:40742:7)
    at guildselect.dart:247:52
    at ink_well._InkResponseState.new.handleTap (back_button.dart.lib.js:61234:31)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.invokeCallback (recognizer.dart.lib.js:222:18)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleTapUp (tap.dart.lib.js:433:20)
    at [_checkUp] (tap.dart.lib.js:224:12)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handlePrimaryPointer (tap.dart.lib.js:171:23)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleEvent (recognizer.dart.lib.js:485:16)
    at [_dispatch] (pointer_router.dart.lib.js:93:9)
    at pointer_router.dart.lib.js:119:26
    at LinkedMap.new.forEach (dart_sdk.js:28056:11)
    at [_dispatchEventToRoutes] (pointer_router.dart.lib.js:117:29)
    at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.route (pointer_router.dart.lib.js:112:37)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleEvent (binding.dart.lib.js:381:26)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (binding.dart.lib.js:369:24)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (view.dart.lib.js:699:13)
    at [_handlePointerEventImmediately] (binding.dart.lib.js:345:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handlePointerEvent (binding.dart.lib.js:315:43)
    at [_flushPointerEventQueue] (binding.dart.lib.js:304:14)
    at [_handlePointerDataPacket] (binding.dart.lib.js:292:38)
    at Object.invoke1 (dart_sdk.js:200378:7)
    at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.new.invokeOnPointerDataPacket (dart_sdk.js:175073:15)
    at [_onPointerData] (dart_sdk.js:176047:49)
    at dart_sdk.js:176592:30
    at dart_sdk.js:176532:9
    at loggedHandler (dart_sdk.js:176223:11)
    at dart_sdk.js:176141:78
    at Object._checkAndCall (dart_sdk.js:5600:16)
    at Object.dcall (dart_sdk.js:5605:17)
    at ret (dart_sdk.js:62582:21)
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2604], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: Since dartssh2 uses dart:io it cannot be compatible with web.

Comment: https://github.com/TerminalStudio/dartssh2/issues/45

Comment: @RichardHeap are you familiar with any packages that I could use instead? if you can provide me with one and restate what youve said previously I can accept the answer

Comment: There is no solution. JavaScript applications cannot open arbitrary sockets.